# Объяснение намерения: "чтобы", "для" — как ставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Что-то вдруг засомневался.

***"Чтобы разрешить уравнение относительно X, умножим обе части уравнения на обратную матрицу".***

***"Для разрешения уравнения относительно X умножим обе части уравнения на обратную матрицу".***

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в первом случае запятая после "X" нужна, а во втором — нет?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, Вы понимаете абсолютно правильно

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае "Чтобы" - подчинительный союз, который связывает два простых в составе сложного. Поэтому запятая нужна. Во втором случае предложение простое и ничем не осложнено